# Angular-translate - Translating a variable to be used in another translation

Tags: angular-translate

From https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement

Given:

```
{
  "MESSAGE": "{{value}} is something.",
  "ANOTHER_KEY": "Anything"
}
```

How can I do something like:

```
$translate('MESSAGE', { value: 'ANOTHER_KEY' });
```

So that "ANOTHER_KEY" gets translated and I end up with "Anything is something"?

I was trying to do it in my controller but it doesn't look right.

```
   $translate('ANOTHER_KEY').then(function(translation) {
        $translate('MESSAGE', {value: translation}).then(function(final_translation) {
            $scope.final_translation = final_translation;
        }
    }, ...
```

It seems too complicated and it gets worse when trying to deal with language changes.

Is this the only way?

**Edit**:
The final result will be used as an attribute of a input, so I don't believe I can use the directive approach.

```
<input type="text" special-attribute="TRANSLATION RESULT HERE">
```

Answer (score 1):

from the code itself, it looks OK. Have you forgotten to inject $translate service to your controller?

Here is working example for your case.

```
angular.module('ngView').controller('TranslateCtrl',function($translate, $scope) {
  $translate('ANOTHER_KEY').then(function (translation) {
      return  $translate('MESSAGE', {value: translation});
    }).then(function(translation) {
      $scope.finalTranslation = translation;
    });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eFw1dVnfliAVleuwQOgX?p=preview

Comment: I can't see why, unless you are trying 2-way binding your translation result.
<input type="text" special-attribute="{{finalTranslation}}">

Comment: I does work but I was thinking if there was a better way do to this kind of thing. If that's the only way then I guess it's ok. I will be doing this kind of translation a lot, so it's kind o a burden not having something ready for this.

Comment: well, there is always 'better way'. For example, what about writing your own filter using translation service?

Comment: That's what I was considering, but this feature felt so natural that I couldn't believe there was no native support for that. I guess I was wrong.